# Результат от нажатия на кнопку Android

Tags: java, android, алгоритм, классы

стоит задача сделать текстовый квест под андроид, при выполнении программы встретил ошибку. 
1) Видим предисловие и выбираем первый шаг
2) Видим первую ситуацию
3) После выбора пункта в первой ситуации отображается не дальнейшее развитие сюжета, а как бы я выбрал бы в пункте 1

В коде уже есть кейс для нажатий 1-1, протестировав я увидел данную ошибку.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

**АКТИВНОСТЬ**

```
package com.example.samsunghomework;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setText("Тебе удалось успешно сдать экзамен и вот ты пришел на свою первую пару. \n" +
                "Ты поздоровался с преподавателем и он предложил тебе присесть на место. \n" +
                "В аудитории было три свободных места, и ты начал думать: \n" +
                "① У окна, рядом с парнем, с которым, кажется можно подружиться. \n" +
                "② У стены, рядом с красивой девушкой. \n" +
                "③ На ближайщем месте к преподавателю, будет хорошо слышно материал.");

    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

        Button but1 = findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        Button but2 = findViewById(R.id.bt2);
        Button but3 = findViewById(R.id.bt3);

        TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);


        int qq = 0;
        int qw = 0;
        int qe = 0;
        int checkmazahaka = 0;


        if (checkmazahaka == 0) {
            switch (view.getId()) { // 1 стадия
                case R.id.bt1:
                    if (checkmazahaka == 0) {
                        qq = 1;
                        checkmazahaka = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                case R.id.bt2:
                    if (checkmazahaka == 0) {
                        qw = 1;
                        checkmazahaka = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                case R.id.bt3:
                    if (checkmazahaka == 0) {
                        qe = 1;
                        checkmazahaka = 1;
                        break;
                    }
            }//1 стадия

        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////



        if (qq == 1) { //2.1
            txt.setText("Ты подошел к парню и присел на место. \n"
                    + "Кажется, ему было все равно на твое появление. \n" +
                    "Твои действия? \n" +
                    "① Развернуться к нему и предложить познакомиться. \n" +
                    "② Предложить ему жевательную резинку. \n" +
                    "③ Продолжить осматриваться по сторонам.");

           switch (view.getId()) { // 1 стадия
                case R.id.bt1:
                    qq = 0; // т.к. qq = 1 выводит другой текст
                    break;

                case R.id.bt2:
                    qq = 2;
                    break;

                case R.id.bt3:
                    qq = 3;
                    break;


            }

        }
        if (qw == 1) {//2.2
            txt.setText("Ты подошел к девушке и присел на место. \n" +
                    "Кажется, она тобой заинтерисовалась... \n" +
                    "Твои действия? \n" +
                    "① Развернуться и предложить познакомиться. \n" +
                    "② Не обращать на ее внимания, стараясь приглядеться к ней. \n" +
                    "③ Посмотреть на нее и улыбнуться.");
            switch (view.getId()) { // 1 стадия
                case R.id.bt1:
                    qq = 4;
                    break;

                case R.id.bt2:
                    qq = 5;
                    break;

                case R.id.bt3:
                    qq = 6;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (qe == 1) {//2.3
            txt.setText("Ты подошел к VIP месту на первой парте и сел перед учителем \n" +
                    "Он заметил твою тягу к знаниям но ничего не сказал \n" +
                    "Твои действия?  \n" +
                    "① Достать телефон и начать в него залипать \n" +
                    "② Преданным взглядом смотреть на преподавателя \n" +
                    "③ Обернуться назад и оглядеть аудиторию");
            switch (view.getId()) { // 1 стадия
                case R.id.bt1:
                    qq = 7;
                    break;

                case R.id.bt2:
                    qq = 8;
                    break;

                case R.id.bt3:
                    qq = 9;
                    break;

            }
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if (qq == 0) {
            txt.setText("Парень оказался не против и с удовольствием с тобой познакомился.\n" +
                    "Он предложил тебе после занятия сходить в KFC.\n" +
                    "Что скажешь?\n" +
                    "① Согласишься и будешь с нетерпением ждать конца пары \n" +
                    "② Откажешься, сославшись на неотложныые дела\n" +
                    "③ Промямлишь что - то непонятное");
        }
        if (qq == 2) {

        }
        if (qq == 3) {

        }
        if (qq == 4) {

        }
        if (qq == 5) {

        }
        if (qq == 6) {

        }
        if (qq == 7) {

        }
        if (qq == 8) {

        }
        if (qq == 9) {

        }


    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bbbbbb"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#bbbbbb"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="①" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="②" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="③" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Не очень понятно какую ошибку.

Comment: Итого
1) идет первая вступительная сцена
2) выбираешь вариант к кому сесть
3) идет сцена как ты сел
4)выбираешь дальнейший шаг но тут вместо дальнейшего программа повторяет как бы я сейчас бы находился при выборе варианта к кому сесть (2)

Comment: Выведите ошибку в лог и покажите проще и быстрее будет. И да вы переменные инициализируете по два раза. Вынесите на уровень класса. И инициализация в он create

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите инкрементируемые переменные из OnClick в OnCreate, иначе при каждом входе в метод  они у вас снова на ноль сбрасываются